Does sets of positive capacity rule out constant functions?
Let $U\subset \Bbb R^d$ be bounded with Lipschitz boundary $K\subset \bar{U}$ be compact.  The capacity of $K$ in $U$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
\text{Cap}_{p}(K, U) := 
    \inf \left\{ 
\int_U |\nabla \varphi|^p \, dx : \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\bar{U}), \, \varphi \geq 1 \text{ on } K 
    \right\}.
\end{align*}
Given  a closed subset $F\subset \Bbb R^d$, we consider the set of smooth functions vanishing in a neighborhood of $F$,  that is,
\begin{align}
    C_{c,F}^\infty(U)\Big\{ u\in C_c^\infty(\bar{U}) \,\,|\,\,  \text{there is $\delta>0$ such that $u=0$ on $F_\delta$}\Big\}
\end{align}
where $F_\delta=\{x\in \Bbb R^d\,\,|\,\, dist(x,F)<\delta\}$ is the $\delta$-tubular neighborhood of $F$. Next, we  introduce the space  $W^{1,p}_F(U)$, $1<p<\infty$ the space of functions that vanish on $F$, as the closure of  $C_{c,F}^\infty(U)$ in the usual Sobolev space  $W^{1,p}(U)$ that is
\begin{align}
W^{1,p}_F(U)= 
    \overline{C_{c,F}^\infty(U)}^{W^{1,p}(U)}, 
\end{align}
Question: if $\text{Cap}(K,U)>0$ show that $1\notin W^{1,p}_K(U)$. Any reference, answer or comment is greatly appreciated.
In the simple situation where $F\subset \partial U$ has positive Hausdorff measure(the restriction of the Lebesgue measure on $\partial U$), i.e., $\mathcal{H}(F)>0$ then by trace theorem we know that $1\notin W^{1,p}_F(U).$  In particular if $F= \partial U$  then we have  $W^{1,p}_F(U)= W^{1,p}_0(U)$.
Note that if $\mathcal{H}(K)>0$ implies $\text{Cap}(K,U)>0$ but the converse is not true. For instance when $K$ is a Cantor dust we have $\text{Cap}(K,U)>0$ and $\mathcal{H}(K)=0$.

I'm not entirely sure whether the details check out, but Sobolev functions have a $p$-quasicontinuous representative, which in particular has well-defined values $p$-capacity almost everywhere. This should mean that any function in $W^{1,p}_K(U)$ vanishes $\operatorname{Cap}_p$-a.e. on $K$, so if $K$ has positive capacity (in $U$), 1 cannot belong there.

@Teri Please can you just direct me to a suitable reference ?

I can recommend "Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations" by Heinonen, Kilpeläinen, Martio; and "Function Spaces and Potential Theory" by Adams, Hedberg

I would like to chime in with Ziemer's Weakly differentiable functions, in particular Chapter 4.5 there. (I suppose Corollary 4.5.3 actually answers the question posed in OP in the affirmative.)
